# testing local https server with mocha/superagent

Tags: node.js, ssl, mocha.js, superagent

So I see there was a pull request a few months ago for superagent to allow you to specify the CA in a request.  It does not appear that the docs were updated to reflect this change, so I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I am trying to test on my local machine a REST service which exposes both http and https endpoints.  All the http ones work fine, the SSL ones....well.....not so much.

After spending all day yesterday running down certificate errors, I am 90% certain I have the server working correctly.  Curl seems to think so, as does a vanilla node request object.

I assume superagent is probably creating a request under the hood - I just need to know how to pass in the CA for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [usage example](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/608cda651db3ac1559a604032878bae3ac16efd7/test/node/https.js) in their tests.

Basically:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    key = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'key.pem'),
    cert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'cert.pem'),
    assert = require('better-assert'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Safe and secure!');
});

var server = https.createServer({
    key: key,
    cert: cert
}, app);

server.listen(8443);

describe('request', function() {
    it('should give a good response', function(done) {
        request
            .get('https://localhost:8443/')
            .ca(cert)
            .end(function(res) {
                assert(res.ok);
                assert('Safe and secure!' === res.text);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    ...
    var user = request.agent({ca: cert});
    ...
```

Full example:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('should');
var request= require('superagent');
var fs = require('fs');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

var validUser = { username: 'test@test.com', password: 'secret111' };

describe('User', function() {
    // provide certificate as agent parameter
    var user = request.agent({ca: cert});

    it("/login", function(done) {
        user
            .get('https://localhost:3000/login')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) throw err;
                // HTTP status should be 200
                res.status.should.equal(200);
                user
                    .post('https://localhost:3000/login')
                    .send(validUser)
                    .end(function(err, res) {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        // HTTP status should be 200
                        res.status.should.equal(200);
                        done();
                        // user will manage its own cookies
                        // res.redirects contains an Array of redirects
                    });
            });
    });

    it("/", function(done) {
        user
            .get('https://localhost:3000/')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) throw err;
                // HTTP status should be 200
                res.status.should.equal(200);
                done();
        });
    });

    it("/logout", function(done) {
        user
            .get('https://localhost:3000/logout')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) throw err;
                // HTTP status should be 200
                res.status.should.equal(200);
                done();
            });
    });

});
```